# clipping polygon against rectangle

Tags: math, svg, polygon, computational-geometry, raster

today I have a (simple) rendering problem for you. My current project gets datas from a file to generate a SVG file. Drawing things as polygon is pretty easy thanks to the SVG format, but I have a single problem: some of my polygons are in AND out of the page (meaning that some parts of them are displayed while the rest is not shown due to the fact they are out of the display limit). In order to optimize the final SVG file I need to reduce my polygon to a simpler form.

Consider the grey rectangle as my page.
Consider the green polygon as the thing I actually draw.

First picture shows you the thing that I actually have while the second picture shows you the final result I want to have.

[image: Polygon and page as I have them now]
[image: Polygon and page as I need to have them]
First I thought to reduce my polygon in simple triangles in order to only draw points in the display limits. But I think a simpler solution exists... if you have it do not hesitate to share it with me :)

EDIT:

I have this tricky case to handle as well :

[image][image]

Thank you.

Comment: So what you really want is polygon clipping and not "reduction to a simpler form". Actually the second form isn't that simple, it's just clipped against a rectangle. If you edit the title to "clipping polygon against rectangle" or something the like, you may get the attention you need.

Comment: Not sure how it will affect performance, but would a [mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) help ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza mask is not needed because everything out of the page boundaries won't be displayed... adding a mask will give the exact same result, but will add a lot of computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Clipping a polygon with a rectangle. We reduce this problem to

   clipping a polygon with a line. We reduce this to an even simpler problem:

   clipping one edge of a polygon with a line. Which is really just

   Finding the intersection of a line segment with a line (if it exists).

The last problem is pretty easy, considering that your lines are vertical or horizontal. Is that enough?

Comment: Pretty easy if we see it like that... that reminds me I forgot to talk about one case, let me edit my question (and thank you for your quick answer by the way)

Comment: A.k.a. Southerland-Hodgman algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm